# Why is Curtus Hooks always yawning

Tags: character, second-string

In the made for [TV movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_String) [Second String](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0194342/), one of the second string players Curtus Hooks played by Shawn Woods is seen yawning at several unexpected moments. The most obvious ones are at the end of a practice session, and again at the start of the first playoff game.

His extra training with substitute quarterback Dan Heller, involves the "graveyard shift" where he runs and jukes past a series of headstones in a cemetery. It feels like a link is being made between these two points, but it isn't explicitly spelled out in the film.

Is there supposed to be some personal issue that causes Hooks to yawn all the time that training with Dan helps him get over, like issues he helps other players with throughout the film?

Comment: I know the spelling of Curtus is odd, but that is the IMDB spelling.